# Using image as background in empty div to cover entire area in a responsive web app

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, background-image

I've seen many topics similar to this one, but nothing has worked so far and they don't quite fit my needs.

I have a responsive web app, which is expected to be used on wide screens and on the smallest mobile devices. A part of the screen needs to be 100% covered by an image for all device sizes (to which the image needs to resize accordingly), while the other has some text content, buttons, etc.

The best way to approach this is with two divs, one has the image, the other the content. Like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="left">
    <!-- Dont want to put anything here, just background img -->
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....
    </p>
    <button>Do something</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I can't get this to work with my div having the background image. I either have to preset the width and height or I need to content in that div, at which point the image only covers as much as the content.

So, my question is how do I get to fill the div to be responsive and always display that background image.

[Here is the full code of what I already have](https://jsfiddle.net/oxfs1vjk/5/)

I do understand that I can simply set the height of my class and I'll have something, so basically this:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

But I want to make sure, the screen stays responsive and adapts depending on the sizes, so hard coding the value doesn't make sense.

Edit: as requested, added a mockup in case someone needs it. The left would be a larger screen such as a monitor, while the right would be a small, mobile device's screen:
[image]

Comment: A mock-up of what the intended result would be helpful. From your description and code I cannot tell if the image on the right should be full viewport height with a varying width or be full width all the time and be part of the viewport height.

Comment: I've already fixed my problem, but here is the mockup in case anyone else has other ways to do it or people need it when coming back to this thread: https://imgur.com/a/5dlsQ

The left side is a large enough screen (think monitor or tablet), while the right one is a mobile device's screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `.left` div use following CSS:

```
position: fixed;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
z-index: -999;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

And delete the `max-width`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked but with one minor changed from originally proposed: I had to remove the position: fixed, or else the content of .right would overlap it.